# MediaPlayer how to stop multiple sounds from playback

Tags: android, media-player, audio

i have a button that plays a sound.
When i push the button multiple times, it plays the sound multiple times.
This is oke, i want this.
But when i click the stop button it must stop all sounds currently playing.
I used:

```
   while (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){mediaPlayer.stop();}
```

but it is not working, the sounds keep on playing. Can someone help me?
Here is my full code:

```
public class HelloSoundboard extends Activity {
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button item1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.item1);
    item1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View view) {
           mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.atyourservice);
           mediaPlayer.start();
       }
    });

    Button stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View view) {
          while (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){mediaPlayer.stop();}
        //  mediaPlayer.stop();
       }
     });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SoundPool` is a much better alternative for this purpose.  I would caution strongly against instantiating multiple `MediaPlayer` instances as most systems do not have the resources to generate many parallel active instances.  You wil find on many device that hitting the button upwards of 5 times will cause a memory based crash.

As far as stopping all active streams, there is not baked-in function for this, but it's easy to accomplish in a manner to similar to your existing code.  As a side note, there is an `autoPause()` method, which halts all streams, but it doesn't truly end their playback (as the method name insinuates).  Here is a simple example to manage your audio streams:

```
//SoundPool initialization somewhere
SoundPool pool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
//Load your sound effect into the pool
int soundId = pool.load(...); //There are several versions of this, pick which fits your sound

List<Integer> streams = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Button item1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.item1);
item1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View view) {
       int streamId = pool.play(soundId, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1, 0, 1.0f);
       streams.add(streamId);
   }
});

Button stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View view) {
      for (Integer stream : streams) {
          pool.stop(stream);
      }
      streams.clear();
   }
});
```

It is much more memory efficient to manage a list of streamID values than `MediaPlayer` instances, and your users will thank you.  Also, note that it is safe to call `SoundPool.stop()` even if the streamID is no longer valid, so you don't need to check for existing playback.

HTH

Comment: It must be noted that SoundPool was made for small sound effects and the buffer must not grow to big. One of my sounds was cut off because of its lengt. so i still need to use MediaPlayer

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about this, but I think is better if you use a SoundPool.

"SoundPool is designed for short clips which can be kept in memory decompressed for quick access, this is best suited for sound effects in apps or games".

"MediaPlayer is designed for longer sound files or streams, this is best suited for music files or larger files".

Comment: Thanks, i experimented a bit with SoundPool but was unable to stop the playback of sounds at all. Also could not find anything about that on WWW, do you know how to stop all sounds in soundpool?

Comment: +1 Because this is a better solution, I just had to add my own answer to fully explain why.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list of `MediaPlayer`s:

```
List<MediaPlayer> mps = new ArrayList<MediaPlayer>();
Button item1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.item1);
item1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View view) {
       MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.atyourservice);
       mp.start();
       mps.add(mp);
   }
});

Button stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View view) {
      for (int i = mps.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) { //changed ++i to --i
          if (mps.get(i).isPlaying()) {
              mps.get(i).stop();
          }
          mps.remove(i);
      }
   }
 });
```

Comment: i got the following error with your code:
The method add(MediaPlayer) in the type List<MediaPlayer> is not applicable for the arguments (void)