# Android MediaPlayer Stop

Tags: android, media-player

I have a view with four ToggleButtons, each playing a different sound at each state. So in total i have eight MediaPlayer instances. When the user selects one toggle button a sound will play, depending on what the value of the toggle button is. Here is my code for one ToggleButton.

```
MediaPlayer pos = MediaPlayer.create(Set.this, R.raw.pos)
MediaPlayer neg = MediaPlayer.create(Set.this, R.raw.neg);

private void onPlayer1Clicked() {
    if (((ToggleButton)Player1).isChecked())
     positive();
   else
     negative();
}

private void positive() {
    pos.start();
}

private void negative() {
    neg.start();
}
```

Where i have come stuck is when another ToggleButton is pressed before the MediaPlayer has stopped, the MediaPlayer plays both tunes until the fist one has finished. I could stop the MediaPlayer on the ToggleButton being pressed but i don't really want to type it out for every button as that would be seven tunes to Stop() at once.

Does anyone know how to stop all MediaPlayer instances with a simple command?

Comment: what kind of sound you have??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SoundPool . It fit better for this purpose.
Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10013407/1503155) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Put all `MediaPlayers` in a [Collection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collection.html).

Then you can just iterate over the collection and stop them.

Comment: Do you know of a good tutorial on using a Collection? Tried googling it but couldn't find anything.

Comment: I think these three are good examples & tutorials for collection [1](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2009/08/04/collections-sort-java/), [2](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/collection_all.htm), [3](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/java_collections.htm)